# Обращение к значению текстового поля не работает

Tags: javascript, dom

На текстовое поле (input type="text") установлено событие onblur, при котором вызывается функция, генерирующая случайное имя:

```
 function checkUsername()
 {
    var oUser = document.getElementById("userName");
    if (oUser.value == "") {
        oUser.value = "Guest" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
    }
 }
```

Все работает, но почему, когда я хочу выбрать не само поле, а сразу его значение, все перестает работать:

```
    function checkUsername()
    {
       var oUser = document.getElementById("userName").value;
       if (oUser == "") {
           oUser = "Guest" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
       }
    }
```

Comment: Я счас занят, потом (к вечеру) напишу вам ответ о том что ваш подход самый что не наесть древний(1998г+) и есть более новый(2003г+) но тоже устаревший который я пока использую и самый новый (2006г+) метод работы с DOM который я пока не освоил...

Comment: На самом деле тут не дело в подходе, мне просто хотелось понять причину проблемы, вот и все. Но буду рад услышать ваш ответ по теме работы с DOM.

Comment: Кстати ссылка в ответе @Heidel ведёт на разновидность подхода 2006+

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На сколько я понимаю, то тут:

```
// получаем объект, изменение его свойств приведет к изменению свойств у объекта userName
var oUser = document.getElementById("userName");

// получаем значение объекта, при этом изменение переменной не приведет к изменению значения у объекта
var oUser2 = document.getElementById("userName").value;
```

Comment: Немного не понял, почему?

Comment: Надо для того чтоб понять читать книгу "JavaScript. Подробное руководство. 6-е издание" сейчас JS это уже не то что можно понять за один присест :). На самом деле все дело в DOM. Лучше не изменять св-ва обьектов HTMLElement а вызывать метод setAttribute:

> Самый простой способ работы с атрибутами предоставляют методы Element.getAttribute и Element.setAttribute. Эти методы используют строки в качестве значений атрибутов и позволяют вообще отказаться от применения объектов Attr.

Comment: @andreyqin, в первом случае получаем объект, а во втором просто значение, которое никак не привязано с объектом.

это как:

    x = 5;
    y = x; // получаем значение х.
    y = 6; // меняем значение у, но х не меняется.

Comment: Да, спасибо, я разобрался :)

Answer (score 1):

А вот такой http://jsfiddle.net/6NCzj/10/ вариант вам не подойдет?

Comment: Дело не в том, подойдет или нет, мне интересно, почему не работает такой вариант

Comment: Не работает потому, что во втором случае в переменной `oUser` храниться значение объекта, а не сам объект, и когда вы присваиваете значение `oUser = "Guest" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);`, то просто меняется значение этой самой переменной, но никакого влияния на объект это не оказывает.

Comment: Собственно,это самое вам в первом ответе и объяснили.

Comment: Все, сейчас прокрутил в голове и разобрался, спасибо!